# How to solve "RenderBox was not laid out:" in ListView.Builder widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, flutter-layout, render

I'm using ListView.Builder inside Expanded widget, but it's through exception

`RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#508c1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1696 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

ListView.builder widget named `LogTimeline`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: timelineList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(),
                    Container(),
                    Container(),
                  ],),
              ],),
          ),}
      ),),}
```

`LogTimeline` widget used in

```
  Wrap(
        children: [
          LogHeader(
            headerTitle: "Overtime log",
          ),
          LogTimeline(
            timelineList: overtimeList,
          ),
        ],
      )
```

when ListView.builder used in a wrap widget, it shows "Bottom OverFlowed"
How can I solve this exception, why this exception occurs,

[Full code link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65024)

Comment: Is this widget in a Column?

Comment: yes, it's used in a column

Comment: Can you post your entire code?

Comment: I replaced the Column widget with Wrap widget, it's displayed "Bottam overflowed by 250pixels"

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: [full code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65024)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Expanded Widget and see

Comment: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Comment: Show Full Code Please